Implementing a version of the clone() API using fork()
I’m working on a project where I need to implement a version of the clone() API using fork(). The original context of the function is a thread-based implementation of task worker creation. Here’s the original code:
int bkwrk_create_worker() {
  unsigned int i;

  for (i = 0; i < MAX_WORKER; i++) {
    void ** child_stack = (void ** ) malloc(STACK_SIZE);
    unsigned int wrkid = i;
    pthread_t threadid;

    sigset_t set;
    int s;

    sigemptyset( & set);
    sigaddset( & set, SIGQUIT);
    sigaddset( & set, SIGUSR1);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, & set, NULL);

    /* Stack grow down - start at top*/
    void * stack_top = child_stack + STACK_SIZE;

    wrkid_tid[i] = clone( & bkwrk_worker, stack_top,
      CLONE_VM | CLONE_FILES,
      (void * ) & i);

    usleep(100);
  return 0;
}

However, when I try to replace clone() with fork(), I run into a problem. The data between the parent and child process is not the same. If worker[i] is assigned to the parent process, then whenever the child process needs it, its task is NULL.
I understand that fork() creates a new process with a copy of the parent’s memory, so changes in the parent’s memory after the fork() do not affect the child. However, clone() with the CLONE_VM flag allows the child and parent to share memory, so changes in one process are visible in the other.
How can I achieve similar behavior with fork()? Is there a way to share specific data between the parent and child process created by fork()?
I have already referred to the following question. What i learnt was both of the fork() and clone() API both used the clone() system call but the fork() API does not provide any argument for the stack, do I need to implement it on my own or I need to use the Inter Process Communication?

If you need specific memory shared between processes, you need shared memory, not fork that behaves like clone (which cannot be done).

Can you change the code to use pthreads instead of Linux-specific clone?
